# IIS7 will not display *.html, but *.aspx works fine

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have a Windows Server 2k8 machine that I am trying to host some vanilla html pages on under the default website as a virtual directory.  When I try to view the page, no html is returned.  I have an application under the default website and that renders the aspx pages in it fine.

Placing an aspx file in the virtual directory works, but plain HTML does not.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the static content role service, see [this article](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-iis7/2008-03-21/) about installing IIS7:

[alt text http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/wpnew/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Dave_IIS7_install/install_iis7_06.png](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/wpnew/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/Dave_IIS7_install/install_iis7_06.png)